# Different section elements overlap in HTML

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I added a section where I can scroll between different tabs to my hTML homepage (`index.html`). Below this, is another section (File download section) which is showing some sort of overlap between elements.

For instance, when I `Inspect Element` on the **Download File** button graphic, the console tell me that it is one of the low lying `<li> elements` from the new scroll section I had added.

[image]

Where could it have gone wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Figured. One of the tabs had substantially large amount of content. So, that was causing the  for the table to autosize and overlap with the Download File button.

I simply decreased my font in that section a bit and reduced the line height so the  is more compact now. Problem solved! Mouse hover leads to button at all times!

Changes were made to .css in this section:

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    font-family: 'SF Mono', sans-serif;;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #eee;
    font-size: 15px;
    line-height: 1.35;
  }
```